# import path for python in django

Tags: python, django, import, path

why is ROOT_URLCONF (default) = 'mysite.urls', rather than just 'urls' even though the settings.py is already inside 'mysite' directory.

from "myApps.views" import *  in url.py
inside myApps directory is confusing as well.

Am I safe to assume that, inside an application(such as mysite),
1. mysite.module_name rather than just plain module_name is the correct path when I'm working on a file in 'mysite' directory and
2. myApp.module_name is the correct path when I'm working on a file in 'myApp' directory?

In a normal python setting, I could look at sys.path, but I'm not sure how I should view sys.path for e.g., mysite/url.py.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Explains mysite is the actual python package you will want to use it to import anyThing inside it

Inside of mysite always use it to importanything including apps

Comment: Suppose I create myApp at the same level as the mySite. so mySite/mySite, mySite/myApp, (the root mySite has no meaning as the doc says).. Why is it 'from mySite.myApp.model import *' rather than 'from myApp.model import *'?